# WinForms Volume Slider/Trackbar User Control

Tags: .net, winforms, slider, volume, trackbar

I'm looking for a trackbar-like user/custom control to use in my .NET 2.0 WinForms app.

Note: I'm NOT asking how to control the volume in a WinForms app.

Anyone knows of a nice looking custom painted slider/trackbar control that could be used in my app to let user set the volume? (such as the ones used in multimedia apps)

Ideally, it should support vertical orientation.

TIA,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an excellent C# tutorial on how to create your own custom trackbar over at CodeGuru:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c12101

The result looks very impressive, and because you are creating your own control you wouldn't have to worry about licensing a 3rd party control. Just make sure to follow the licensing for the sample code as well. :)

Comment: Jon, thanks for the pointer. Not sure I have time to dive into it. Would have preferred a ready-to-use class. But it's certainly interesting a reading.

Answer (score 5):

There's a TrackBar control, it's just a little hard to find it because it has no category on toolbar. Open "All Windows Forms". According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx) it has been there since .NET 1.0

Comment: Codeguard, thanks for your answer. I know of this control. I was looking for something that look more specifically like a volume slider/trackbar.