# Is there a way to allow default control painting, while adding my own painting?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I was planning on creating a custom TrackBar class that implements from TrackBar.  I want it to look/feel **EXACTLY** the same, other than a display on the value just to the side of the track itself.

I've been seeing that you can either let the OS draw the control, or allow the user draw it, but then the user must draw **EVERYTHING**.  Is there a way for me to allow the OS draw the control, and then let me draw the value?

EDIT:
The key I want to emphasize is, I want to only add the drawing the value, rather than drawing the whole thing myself.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Sorry, that is a very good point.  I am targeting a winforms class.

Comment: See @Aaron Murgatroyd's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551889/how-to-make-an-ownerdraw-trackbar-in-winforms),  not the accepted answer!

Comment: Thank you!! This did it.  I spent all day searching for it, and you apparently found it in less than hour :)

Comment: Well, let's make is 3 minutes and a little luck. I tried to implement owner-drawing for a test and looked for a little help..