# Values on trackbar

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

Quick question;
In C#, Windows Forms, is it not possible, to have a System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar show all its values, next to its ticks?
I have not been able to find any way of doing this, which suprises me abit.
Is there another way, to get this behavior? I really would like to avoid, creating 25 labels, and writing on them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625728/winforms-volume-slider-trackbar-user-control http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c12101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a User Control with the TrackBar in it and generate labels at runtime (placement of the labels goes according to tick values).

I did something similar some time ago with a ProgressBar instead of TrackBar, but the logic should still apply. Don't have code at hand right now I'm afraid, will try to dig it up.

Comment: Please do dig it up.